# Connecting Arduino to a remote MySQL database using DNS and WiFi

Tags: mysql, dns, arduino, wifi, esp8266

I am currently trying to connect my ESP8266 to an Azure MySQL database using WiFi and DNS. It seems like the WiFi library does not natively support DNS, only IP however Azure does not support static IP, therefore I need to use DNS.

This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <WiFi.h>                  
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>
#include <Dns.h>

byte mac_addr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
char hostname[] = "something.mysql.database.azure.com"; //replace something with database name

IPAddress server_ip; 
char user[] = "root";              // MySQL user login username
char password[] = "secret";        // MySQL user login password

// WiFi card example
char ssid[] = "WiFiSSID";    // your SSID
char pass[] = "secret";       // your SSID Password

WiFiClient client;            // Use this for WiFi instead of EthernetClient
MySQL_Connection conn((Client *)&client);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial); // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only

  // Begin WiFi section
  int status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  if ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't get a wifi connection");
    while(true);
  }
  // print out info about the connection:
  else {
    Serial.println("Connected to network");
    IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
//    Particle.process(); Seemingly need to call this for WiFi.dnsServerIP() to be available but gives "out of scope error".
    DNSClient dns;
    dns.begin(WiFi.dnsServerIP());
    dns.getHostByName(hostname, server_ip);


  }
  // End WiFi section

  Serial.println("Connecting...");
  if (conn.connect(server_ip, 3306, user, password)) {
    delay(1000);
  }
  else
    Serial.println("Connection failed.");
  conn.close();
}

void loop() {
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 10), Board: "SparkFun ESP8266 Thing Dev, 80 MHz, 512K (no SPIFFS), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

C:\Users\Mathi\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\wifi_hostname_sketchB\wifi_hostname_sketchB.ino: In function 'void setup()':

wifi_hostname_sketchB:65: error: 'class WiFiClass' has no member named 'dnsServerIP'

     dns.begin(WiFi.dnsServerIP());

                    ^

Multiple libraries were found for "Ethernet.h"
 Used: C:\Users\Mathi\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.1\libraries\Ethernet
 Not used: D:\Programs\Arduino IDE\Arduino\libraries\Ethernet
exit status 1
'class WiFiClass' has no member named 'dnsServerIP'

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I have tried using the Particle.process function but it kept giving me an 'Out of scope' error. Most people fixed this by changing the firmware but did not help me.

I got most of the code from https://github.com/ChuckBell/MySQL_Connector_Arduino 
I followed the guide for accessing the MySQL database with WiFi, however this did not include DNS.

Comment: Maybe just try `WiFi.hostByName(hostname, server_ip);` to get the server IP?

Comment: And where exactly would I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't use DNSclient it won't work with WiFi use WiFi.hostByName instead. Took me 2 days to find this gem..

```
IPAddress server_ip;
WiFi.hostByName("www.google.com",server_ip);
Serial.println(server_ip); // server_ip will contain the ip address of google.com
```

Comment: @JohnSmith, not this. the WiFiClient.connect() function can take server name as parameter and resolves then name 'behind the scene'. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

the WiFi library [WiFiWebClient example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiWebClient) uses host name to connect to the web server.

```
char server[] = "www.google.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
```

Answer (score -2):

Since microsoft Azure does only support DNS and the ESP8266 WiFi library only supports static IP, they will not work together. You could use google cloud instead, since this supports static IP.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. ESP8266 Wifi library does support DNS. See Ke Wang's answer below.